# OSError: Could not find libspatialindex_c library file on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, geopandas, fiona, libspatialindex

System: Mac OSX

Im relatively new user of Python and currently exploring GIS. 
Trying to read a shape file with geopandas however I am getting:
OSError: Could not find libspatialindex_c library file

Using Python 3.7 normally, but since there are dependencies issues with geopandas on this, followed advice here to run on Python2.

What i've done here is with mac terminal, created new environment with python2 and installed geopandas there and tried to read shape file.

> conda create -n mytest python=2.7 geopandas -c conda-forge
>
> source activate mytest
>
> > import geopandas
> >
> > geopandas.read_file('Random_points_twitter.shp')

```
  id   xcoord    ycoord  data_twitt
```

0     0  5.27735  50.25398           0

1      1  3.29896  51.32356           1

2      2  3.29896  51.32356           2

I am successfully able to read this in terminal. But in the browser, it returns me an error.

What I've done was first install jupyter on my new env and got a notebook running on browser(code below)

> > (mytest) conda install jupyter
> >
> > (mytest) jupyter-notebook

On browser with the new notebook,tried to import and read the shape file (similar to what i did in terminal) but it gives me this error:

#### #

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 import geopandas

/Users/rldy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geopandas/**init**.py in ()
----> 1 from geopandas.geoseries import GeoSeries
      2 from geopandas.geodataframe import GeoDataFrame
      3 
      4 from geopandas.io.file import read_file
      5 from geopandas.io.sql import read_postgis

/Users/rldy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geopandas/geoseries.py in ()
     10 
     11 from geopandas.plotting import plot_series
---> 12 from geopandas.base import GeoPandasBase, _series_unary_op, _CoordinateIndexer
     13 
     14

/Users/rldy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geopandas/base.py in ()
     12 
     13 try:
---> 14     from rtree.core import RTreeError
     15     HAS_SINDEX = True
     16 except ImportError:

/Users/rldy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rtree/**init**.py in ()
----> 1 from .index import Rtree
      2 
      3 from .core import rt
      4 
      5 **version** = '0.8.3'

/Users/rldy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rtree/index.py in ()
      3 import pprint
      4 
----> 5 from . import core
      6 import ctypes
      7 try:

/Users/rldy/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rtree/core.py in ()
    123 
    124     if lib_name is None:
--> 125         raise OSError("Could not find libspatialindex_c library file")
    126 
    127     rt = ctypes.CDLL(lib_name)

OSError: Could not find libspatialindex_c library file

#### #

My conda list (below) already has libspatial installed yet when running on Jupyter Notebook using browser gives me this error. Any ideas?

```
backports:                     1.0-py27_1            conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache: 1.4-py27_1            conda-forge
backports_abc:                 0.5-py27_0            conda-forge
ca-certificates:               2017.11.5-0           conda-forge
certifi:                       2017.11.5-py27_0      conda-forge
clangdev:                      5.0.0-default_0       conda-forge
click:                         6.7-py_1              conda-forge
click-plugins:                 1.0.3-py27_0          conda-forge
cligj:                         0.4.0-py27_0          conda-forge
curl:                          7.55.1-0              conda-forge
cycler:                        0.10.0-py27_0         conda-forge
descartes:                     1.1.0-py27_0          conda-forge
enum34:                        1.1.6-py27_1          conda-forge
expat:                         2.2.5-0               conda-forge
fiona:                         1.7.9-py27_0          conda-forge
freetype:                      2.8.1-0               conda-forge
freexl:                        1.0.4-0               conda-forge
functools32:                   3.2.3.2-py27_1        conda-forge
geopandas:                     0.3.0-py27_0          conda-forge
geos:                          3.6.2-1               conda-forge
geotiff:                       1.4.2-1               conda-forge
giflib:                        5.1.4-0               conda-forge
hdf4:                          4.2.13-0              conda-forge
hdf5:                          1.10.1-1              conda-forge
icu:                           58.2-0                conda-forge
intel-openmp:                  2018.0.0-h8158457_8              
jpeg:                          9b-2                  conda-forge
json-c:                        0.12.1-0              conda-forge
kealib:                        1.4.7-4               conda-forge
krb5:                          1.14.2-0              conda-forge
libcxx:                        5.0.0-0               conda-forge
libdap4:                       3.18.3-2              conda-forge
libgdal:                       2.1.4-9               conda-forge
libgfortran:                   3.0.1-h93005f0_2                 
libiconv:                      1.15-0                conda-forge
libnetcdf:                     4.4.1.1-10            conda-forge
libpng:                        1.6.34-0              conda-forge
libpq:                         9.6.3-0               conda-forge
libspatialindex:               1.8.5-1               conda-forge
libspatialite:                 4.3.0a-19             conda-forge
libssh2:                       1.8.0-2               conda-forge
libtiff:                       4.0.9-0               conda-forge
libxml2:                       2.9.7-0               conda-forge
llvmdev:                       5.0.0-default_0       conda-forge
matplotlib:                    2.1.2-py27_0          conda-forge
mkl:                           2018.0.1-hfbd8650_4              
munch:                         2.2.0-py27_0          conda-forge
ncurses:                       5.9-10                conda-forge
numpy:                         1.14.0-py27h8a80b8c_1            
openjpeg:                      2.3.0-2               conda-forge
openssl:                       1.0.2n-0              conda-forge
pandas:                        0.22.0-py27_0         conda-forge
pcre:                          8.39-0                conda-forge
pip:                           9.0.1-py27_1          conda-forge
proj4:                         4.9.3-5               conda-forge
psycopg2:                      2.7.3.2-py27_0        conda-forge
pyparsing:                     2.2.0-py27_0          conda-forge
pyproj:                        1.9.5.1-py27_0        conda-forge
pysal:                         1.14.3-py27_0         conda-forge
python:                        2.7.14-4              conda-forge
python-dateutil:               2.6.1-py27_0          conda-forge
pytz:                          2017.3-py_2           conda-forge
readline:                      7.0-0                 conda-forge
rtree:                         0.8.3-py27_0          conda-forge
scipy:                         1.0.0-py27h793f721_0             
setuptools:                    38.4.0-py27_0         conda-forge
shapely:                       1.6.4-py27_0          conda-forge
singledispatch:                3.4.0.3-py27_0        conda-forge
six:                           1.11.0-py27_1         conda-forge
sqlalchemy:                    1.2.1-py27_0          conda-forge
sqlite:                        3.20.1-2              conda-forge
ssl_match_hostname:            3.5.0.1-py27_1        conda-forge
subprocess32:                  3.2.7-py27_0          conda-forge
tk:                            8.6.7-0               conda-forge
tornado:                       4.5.3-py27_0          conda-forge
wheel:                         0.30.0-py27_2         conda-forge
xerces-c:                      3.2.0-0               conda-forge
xz:                            5.2.3-0               conda-forge
zlib:                          1.2.11-0              conda-forge
```

Comment: You also need to install `notebook` in your environment. You can see from the paths in the error message, that it is not coming from the environment in which you installed geopandas.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem from the below code.

```
sudo apt-get install automake
sudo apt-get install libtool
sudo apt-get install pkg-config
curl -L https://github.com/libspatialindex/libspatialindex/archive/1.8.5.tar.gz | tar xz
cd libspatialindex-1.8.5/
./autogen.sh 
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Running `brew install spatialindex` in terminal on mac solved the problem.